# How to output settings.html json data into a query in shopify

Tags: json, shopify

I am attempting to output a name of a collection from the json data from the customize page of Shopify theme. I can do this fine when its on its own.

For Example:

```
{{ settings.collection1 }}
```

However I want it in a query and am not sure how to do this. Where the {{settings.collection1 is I want to output the collection name and have the products be outputted in that collection but currently all that happens is the collection name itself is outputted.

```
{% for product in collections.{{settings.collection1}}.products %}
   {% capture productLink %}{{ product.url }}{% endcapture %}
   <a href="{{ productLink }}">{{product.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looked into the templating documentation, turns out I needed use square brackets inside of a tag when using a object.

```
{% for product in collections.[[settings.collection1]].products %}
   {% capture productLink %}{{ product.url }}{% endcapture %}
   <a href="{{ productLink }}">{{product.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Like This

```
[[settings.collection1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`{{ ... }}` is used for output. You can [access a collection with dot notation or square brackets](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/handle#attributes-handle). For example, these 2 lines do the same thing:

```
collections.frontpage.products
collections['frontpage'].products
```

If you want to get the collection name from the settings object, the square bracket notation is the one you'll need to use:

```
collections[settings.collection1].products
```